# What does ringing the bell in Belfry Luna/Sol do?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I explored Belfry Luna/Sol and I pull the lever that rings the bell but I totally failed to understand what does that actually do. Apparently, nothing happens, at least in single players but since those are pvp areas I wonder if it triggers some kind of online events.

Comment: I read somewhere that ringing the bell opens the door to the gargoyle boss fight, but I'm not sure if this is true. I had already rung it when I got there, so I don't know if the door was closed before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're referring to the lever at the top of the ladder in Belfry Luna[The area you access via the Pharros' Lockstone passage] then it opens the gate blocking the mist for the Gargoyle boss fight.

The second bell in Belfry Sol (the sunlight roof area) unlocks the gate at the end of the rooftop area. I confirmed this today.

Comment: Yep I'm referring to both. Now that you mention it I remember the gate in front of the gate in Belfry Luna!

Comment: This is all that ringing the bells does, simply unlocks the boss fights. There is no in-game special event that is triggered by ringing both.